# Trying to go full screen crashes my app

Tags: android

This is my a portion of my android `manifest.xml`

```
 <application
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And this is part of my `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Whenever I attempt to make the app run in full screen landscape it crashes upon launching. However if I remove the lines that set the orienation and such the apps runs just fine.

And the Logcat data: http://pastebin.com/D9zRVfBy

Comment: It would appear that I have posted the Logcat from two runs, the error starts on line:115

Comment: How about you clear it out, run it again, and edit it into your post so we know we're looking at the correct stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

If you're extending `ActionBarActivity` then you have to use one of the support library themes, i.e. Theme.AppCompat. It tells you exactly that in the stack trace.

For example:

```
<application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Of course you can also use your own theme, but it would have to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`